# How to access mailbox folders with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

Good morning everybody,

I am using Spring Integration to read incoming emails and parse them.

I would like to implement the following behaviour: move the email to a dedicated folder once it has been processed.

I have a Spring service getting and processing the email.

```
<!-- Mail listeners -->
<int:channel id="receiveChannel" datatype="javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage"/>

<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="incomingEmailsAdapter"
    store-uri="${inboundMail.storeUri}"
    channel="receiveChannel"
    should-delete-messages="false"
    should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
    auto-startup="${inboundMail.startup}"
    java-mail-properties="javaMailInboundProperties">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="${inboundMail.nb.poll}" fixed-rate="${inboundMail.nb.rate}"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator id="serviceActivator" input-channel="receiveChannel" ref="mailService" method="handleMail"/>
```

In the handleMail method, when I am trying to access a folder where I can store the information, I always have an exception saying the folder doesn't exist.
The method exists() on the folder always returns false.

```
    public void handleMail(MimeMessage message) {
    try {
    ...
        Folder folder = message.getFolder();
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Folder test = folder.getFolder("Transmitted");
```

My root folder is inbox.
I have created a "Transmitted" folder. But when I test the "test" folder existence, false is always returned. As a consequence I cannot move my message to the "Transmitted" folder.

I have also tried this:

```
         Store fstore = folder.getStore();
         Folder successFolder = fstore.getFolder("Transmitted");
```

But the result is the same. successFolder.exists() returns false;

How should I access the folder?

Thanks in advance

Gilles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by using

```
Folder[] folders = folder.getStore().getDefaultFolder().list("*");
```

The name of the folder, in this case was: INBOX.Transmitted

Regards

Gilles